# I need to make a health system in a python game

Tags: python, text, system

I'm planning to add a health system in a python game. I want it to be in a game_state['']. How would I go about making the health system relative to the damage you've taken?

Like this:

```
    print "Your health is", game_state['health']
    print "Zombie attacks"
    global health = game_state['health'] - 10
    print "Your health is", game_state['health'] - 10
```

Would something like that work? Can I use global?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do this?

```
game_state['health'] = game_state['health'] - 10
```

Comment: Yes sorry, forgot to change that global thing... Wrote that first, but then figured it would be better using game_state. Would that work though?

Comment: Why would you think it would not work? If your `game_state` is something that globally stores player information, it should work just fine to add health there as well.

Comment: Or wait... Do you know a way I could make it so that it always checks for the health? Like every time something happens? If it goes down to 0, I want it to prompt a death message. By the way, I just started programming in python yesterday

Comment: Make `game_state` an object with a property `health` and a method `reduce_health()` that deducts 10 from `health` then checks if health is 0 and if so prompts the death message. Might be overkill though (pun not intended)

Comment: That depends on how your game is built; for example if you have a main game loop, you could add a check there that checks it before any further action is taken. Or you could make function that checks the health and redirects the flow in some way.

Comment: @Stuart Thank you! I will try that!
poke: The game is text based, like zork

Comment: @Stuart I don't understand the concept of methods actually... How would I go about making one? And how does it work by autochecking all the time?

Answer (score 0):

(In response to the questioner's comment on an earlier answer) This is how you could implement health with a class.

```
import os
class GameStatus:
    def __init__(self):
        self.health = 100
    def reduce_health(self):
        self.health -= 10
        if self.health <= 0:
            game_over()

def main_game():
    game_status = GameStatus()
    #...
    # when player gets hurt
    game_status.reduce_health()
    # ...

def game_over():
    print ('"game over, sorry"')
    os._exit(1)
```

As I said this is overkill, especially if you have a single game loop and probably only need to check the health once at the end of each loop, but potentially useful if you start adding more complexity.